# t-test degrees of freedom

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm having difficulty in understanding this fairly common question:

"A teacher is trying to determine whether or not a new teaching method is effective in helping students understand a challenging concept. The teacher evenly divides 30 students into two randomly selected groups. the first group will be taught using a traditional method, while the second group will be taught using the new method. At the end of the unit, all of the students will take the same exam. Assuming a 95 percent level of confidence, which of the following decisions should be made regarding hypothesis below?"

$$H_0:μ1=μ2$$
$$H_a:μ1<μ2$$

(A) Reject the mull hypothesis if the test statistic is greater then -1.761

(B) Reject the mull hypothesis if the test statistic is less then -1.761

(C) Reject the mull hypothesis if the p-value >0.05

(D) Reject the mull hypothesis if $\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}=-1.5$

(E) Reject the mull hypothesis if $\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}=-2.5$

the correct answer is B:
in which $df=15-1=14$ was used to find the above critical value.

But in my opion, the answer used a wrong test (t-test for population mean claim) here.

this is a question for testing difference of means in two populations. the hypothesis should be:

$$H_0:μ1−μ2=0$$
$$H_a:μ1−μ2<0$$

and $t=\frac{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2} -0}{s_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}$
which should have a $df=n1+n2−2=15+15−2=28$

Can anyone help verify my belief?

the original question is here:

[Questoin 10](https://books.google.ca/books?id=d3J6EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22A%20teacher%20is%20trying%20to%20determine%20whether%20or%20not%20a%20new%20teaching%22&source=bl&ots=Uyuz_AGfEJ&sig=ACfU3U1ceN0uozPujMSlps2k0kAXo3moww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO8cLxgsr6AhWTD1kFHUtgDNgQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22A%20teacher%20is%20trying%20to%20determine%20whether%20or%20not%20a%20new%20teaching%22&f=false)

Comment: *Which* version of the Student t-test is being applied?  Until that is specified, this question has no definite answer.

Comment: I think both t-test for population mean claim and t-test for difference in populations means can be used. but the methods to calculate the degree of freedom are different. I wonder if both test will produce same result, if not which test is the correct test.

Comment: I believe t-test for difference in populations means is more appropriate. I believe the degree of freedom should be calculated as $df=n_1+n_2-2=28$. but the answer was $df=15-1=14$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

Comment: Welch's_t-test is out of consideration here as the sample standard deviations are not given in the question. The answer key clearly uses the t-test for population mean claim with $df=15-1=14$. My view is that t-test for population mean claim should be used only when comparing to a known/fixed mean for a single population. But this question is about comparing two means from two population.

Comment: Since we don't have access to the answer key, that's not a consideration we can apply.  Please include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: the original question is here:

Comment: [Questoin 10][1]


  [1]: https://books.google.ca/books?id=d3J6EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22A%20teacher%20is%20trying%20to%20determine%20whether%20or%20not%20a%20new%20teaching%22&source=bl&ots=Uyuz_AGfEJ&sig=ACfU3U1ceN0uozPujMSlps2k0kAXo3moww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO8cLxgsr6AhWTD1kFHUtgDNgQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22A%20teacher%20is%20trying%20to%20determine%20whether%20or%20not%20a%20new%20teaching%22&f=false

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with the original poster, @techie11, and think none of the answers would be correct under the usual assumptions of a question like this.  I would assume the degrees of freedom should be 28, and the cutoff for the *t* statistic would be 1.701 or -1.701, with a one-sided test.

Comment: Thank you @Sal Mangiafico

Comment: The link goes to a page that is not available.  This is a test review book, so enough said: don't assume the questions are good or the answers are reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the null and alt hypotheses

0: μ1 − μ2=0
: μ1 − μ2<0.

and

0: μ1 = μ2
: μ1 < μ2

Are the same thing because if μ1 = μ2 then μ1 − μ2 = 0 and likewise if μ1 < μ2 then μ1 − μ2 < 0, they are different ways of stating the same thing.

AS for the test, it should be the two sample difference of means t-test and you are correct the df should be (n1+n2)-2=28